# NetLogo import string data

Tags: file-io, netlogo

I'm trying to import a txt file in the following format. However, NetLogo keeps dumping the following error.

> Illegal number format (line number 2, character 1)
>    error while observer running FILE-READ
>    called by procedure HOLIDAY-FILE-IMPORT
>    called by procedure SETUP
>    called by procedure GO
>    called by Button 'go'

The file consists of Strings. However, it works fine when i convert the data into integers. Anyone can advise how to read strings in txt in NetLogo?

Comment: Are the strings just text or are there quotes around them? The `file-read` item in the manual explicitly states "Note that strings need to have quotes around them." The first part of the first line of text would help immeasurably.

Comment: If you want help, you really need to show us both the contents of your file, _and_ the code you are using to try to read it. Otherwise we're just playing a guessing game. Please edit your question to improve it.